MapStruct doesn’t regenerate mappers after updating Entity or DTO classes
I’m writing a Spring Boot REST application (Java 17). For mapping my classes from Entity to DTO and reverse I use MapStruct library (v 1.6.2). For implementation DTO I use java records. For generating getters and setters in Entity classes I use Lombok (v 1.18.34). I use Maven as a project build system.
MapStruct successfully generates correct mappers and stores it in target/generated-sources directory. But after mappers are generated, when I update my Entities of DTOs (e.g. rename field) MapStruct doesn’t update generated mappers. So I have to delete generated mappers after each update of my Entities of DTO classes in order to make MapStruct generate them again. Are there any possible solutions for fixing this problem or automating the process of regeneration?
I suppose the problem might be in MapStruct or Maven compiler plugin configuration. Here is my configuration:
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.13.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <mapstruct.version>1.6.2</mapstruct.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.34</lombok.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                </exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${java.version}</source>
            <target>${java.version}</target>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                <!-- Order is important! Lombok first! -->
                <path>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                </path>
                <path>
                    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                    <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                </path>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>

The approach I use at the moment is manually deleting the target/generated-sources directory. Also I know about a feature of Intellij IDEA of running tasks before the application launch (e.g. mvn clean) but it slows down the launch.
I want MapStruct to automatically update generated mappers after I update my Entity or DTO classes.

This question is similar to: MapStruct + Lombok together not compiling: unknown property in result type. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
You are probably just missing the lombok-mapstruct-binding.

In your pom, there is no need to put also mapstruct-processor in the <dependency> section, it's enough to have it under the <annotationProcessorPaths>. Also, put <scope>optional</scope> or <scope>provided</scope> for lombok in the dependencies.
An example of combining both lombok and mapstruct can be found here (https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/main/mapstruct-lombok/pom.xml), these sources are mantained by the mapstruct dev group, so they may be considered "officials". Check that pom and see how to include the lombok-mapstruct-binding to enhance compatibility.
Anyway, less than a maven issue, it seems more like an IDE one (IntelliJ, right?). Please check if there is any warnings or errors in the IDE console that may give you an evidence of what is not working in the automatic updates of the generated code.
